# Как заставить систему использовать несколько файлов passwd?

Tags: linux

Собираю `Linux From Scratch`, но особенный. Я хочу сделать жесткое разделение базовой и остальной системы. То есть, должно быть два раздела: корневой в `read-only`, и второй - уже `r/w`.

Но беда в том, что я хочу использовать несколько файлов `passwd` и `groups`. Причина проста: необходимо, чтобы программы, в случае невозможности системы подмонтировать `rw` раздел, все равно понимали root пользователя (а не выдавали "I have no name!" и прочую ерунду).

Да и в целом, хочу изначально записать в систему некоторых системных пользователей и группы, помимо `root`-а. То есть надо заставить систему использовать файл `/usr/local/etc/passwd` (да, `RW`-раздел будет монтироваться в `/usr/local`) для сторонних пользователей и групп и `/etc/passwd` для системных.

Можно ли без залезания в исходники (`glibc`, `musl`, `bionic`), заставить систему искать файлы аутентификации (и писать в них) по определённым правилам? И если да - то как эти правила описать?

Comment: может лучше оверлей?

Comment: overlayfs, вы имеете в виду? Нет, я хочу предусмотреть случай "а если /usr/local не смонтируется или не должен быть смонтирован?"

Comment: Так под оверлеем останется исходная версия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/usr/local/etc/passwd создавай на RO разделе. /etc/passwd симлинком на этот путь. Когда смонтируется /usr/local/, то этот файл подменится. Но нужно будет продублировать системных пользователей в файле на rw.

Но то что вы описываете делается через настройку /etc/nsswitch.conf. Тут я вижу объединение баз, но не вижу как поменять путь для модулей compat или files. Похоже единственный способ - создать и скомпилировать плагин скопировав его из стандартного.

Ещё один способ - настроить локальный ldap.

Для systemd систем можно пользователей и группы [прописать в systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/nss-systemd.html).